React-jsonschema-form: Conditional logic within the UI-schema
Let's say I have a simple schema within react-jsonschema-form - with one textfield and a checkbox.
const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    name: { type: 'string' },
    disableInput: { type: 'boolean' },
  },
} ;

Would it be possible to define the uiSchema in a way that allows disabling the textfield if the checkbox is clicked, is it possible to have conditional login within it?

Yup. Just define a variable and set it to true/false based on conditional logic.
